# Unable to dial using rild-debug?

Tags: android, c, sockets

Im trying to use dial using rild-debug socket. but when im doing it sometimes the modem crash occurs and other times rild crash occurs. Im unable to get through the problem even after disabling the Phone app. 
Someone please post your suggestion over this problem.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command "chmod 666 /dev/socket/rild" and look the data format in RIL.JAVA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298750/how-to-connect-to-rild-socket